# How can I split URL with htaccess by "?"

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

For example:

```
ex.com/read?id=1
```

should open

```
ex.com/route.php?action=read&id=1
```

but url won`t changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)\?id=(.+)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /route.php?action=$1&id=%2 [QSD,R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=(.*)&id=(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^    /%1?id=%2 [QSD,L,NE]
```

First I match request that contains query string `id=whatever` then redirect it with new query string.
Then I match new URI which contains new query string `action=whatever&id=whatever` and redirect  it internally to same original path.

**QSD** flag is is available in Apache version 2.4.0 and later https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html , I added to discard previous query string and prevent it to be appended.

Clear browser cache then test these rules .

**UPDATE:**
As per your comment , you want to open `/route.php?action=read&id=1` internally while `/read?id=1` in browser so , you could do what starkeen answered , but with specific query string and general URI it should look like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /route.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So if query string is existing and strat with `id=whatever` , `/abc?id=123` will get internally from `/route.php?action=abc&id=123` and the previous query string will be appending with new one

Comment: Thanks, your variant is work, but I added before RewriteCond `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` because it was infinity loop. Can you tell me how make url won't changing(ex. requested `/read?id=1`, opened `/route.php?action=read&id=1`, but in browser viewed as `/read?id=1`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `RewriteRule` in your `/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^read/?$ /route.php?action=root [QSA,L]
```

This will rewrite `/read?id=1` to `/route.php?action=read&id=1` . You do not read to write `&id=1` in the Rule's destination as QSA automatically adds it to the Rewrite destination.